# ¿Un server debe tener acceso a internet correr una pagina .NET dentro de una Intranet?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Actualmente trabajo en modo local con una  Web application desarrollada en .NET usando c#, Html y JavaScript, la cual funciona perfectamente (en modo local ).

Pero, cuando hago la publicacion en el server de esta Web App, las funcionalidades de la misma se pierden, debido a que el Jquery no lo reconoce dentro de las librerias Jquery UI, Data Tables y Bootstrap.js.

Es importante mencionar que el server donde se instaló el IIS para Desplegar la Web se encuentra dentro de una intranet y no tiene acceso libre a internet; y es por esto que todas las librerias JS antes mencionadas las descargue e inclui dentro del mismo proyecto para no estar tomando referencias externas y evitar ese tipo de problema ( aunque esos scripts se ejecuten del lado del cliente ).

Pero aún así el proyecto sigue sin funcionar, y por eso me pregunto, es necesario que el server cuente con acceso a internet para poder ejecutar esos scripts aunque estén incluidos en el proyecto?

```
<head id="myHeader" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/jquery-3.3.1.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/jquery-ui.min.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/underscore.js") %>'></script> </head>
```

He declarado los scripts de esta forma en la página web, si alguien tiene idea de que puede estar sucediendo, en verdad agradezco el apoyo.

[image: Eso me aparece en el Jqueri UI]

[image: Eso me aparece en el]

La primer imagen representa lo que me marca en el Jquery-UI y la segunda en el Data Tables.

Comment: Bienvenido.  No es necesario que el server cuente con acceso. ¿Podrías verificar que las librerías están fisicamente en la publicación que subiste al IIS?

Comment: @JYass Hola, muchas gracias, disculpa, soy un tanto nuevo en este tema, me podrias orientar en que ruta puedo encontrar la publicacion?, muchas gracias!

Comment: @JYass ya encontré los archivos, y si, todos los archivos están en la carpeta donde se publicaron, alguna idea sobre qué puede estar generando el error?

Comment: Incluye en la pregunta el código con jquery que no funciona,

Comment: @JYass ahí lo adjunté, el error lo comienza a lanzar desde los scripts externos

Comment: PooChristmas para no tener problema inclui en forma completa en la solución la carpeta JS, eso hará que en el webdeploy copie todas las librerías JS en el servidor, luego complila y hace el deploy y debería arrancar tu proyecto en el servidor sin inconvenientes

Comment: Hola @TianZi , todas las librerias JS las tengo dentro de una carpeta JS en modo local y en el server parece la misma estructura con los mismos archivos, es decir, las librerias existen en la solución, sin embargo de alguna manera no las está reconociendo. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: @PoorChristmas muy bien. ¿Podrías verificar si todos los archivos incluidos de jquery son la última versión de cada uno? Así mismo, verificar en el web.config la siguiente línea: <compilation debug="false"> ¿que valor posee?

Comment: "Jquery-UI y la segunda en el Data Tables." ----> ¿Esta incluido el Jquery? Porque esas ocupan Jquery para funcionar

Comment: Tiene pinta de que no encuentra el fichero de jquery. Mira si lo estás cargando bien.